# how to decode rsa with given p,q and e

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

```
p: 36595219896620598203466837041441890226020928028223099101100300133334608406956417
q: 30995374714748002222830087470985334838922058265073459880006631044742483128394347
e: 65537
c: 112551517443367600226914124474656800456883252179897098198626860064436836858554837037004323690904898146330897248584664231803632050963580641362896311366999264714
```

i tried this but didnt work it may contain some errors

```
def egcd(a,b):
    x,y, u,v = 0,1, 1,0
    while a != 0:
        q, r = b//a, b%a
        m, n = x-u*q, y-v*q
        b,a, x,y, u,v = a,r, u,v, m,n
        gcd = b
    return gcd, x, y

def main():

    p = 36595219896620598203466837041441890226020928028223099101100300133334608406956417
    q = 30995374714748002222830087470985334838922058265073459880006631044742483128394347
    e = 65537
    ct = 112551517443367600226914124474656800456883252179897098198626860064436836858554837037004323690904898146330897248584664231803632050963580641362896311366999264714

    # compute n
    n = p * q

    # Compute phi(n)
    phi = (p - 1) * (q - 1)

    # Compute modular inverse of e
    gcd, a, b = egcd(e, phi)
    d = a

    print( "n:  " + str(d) );

    # Decrypt ciphertext
    pt = pow(ct, d, n)
    print( "pt: " + str(pt) )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You've provided the code, but haven't shown what's supposed to be wrong with it. Please [edit] your question provide example outputs and expected outputs.

Comment: I assume the problem here is in your egcd, and I think you have attempted to implement the extended Euclidean algorithm.  At the end of egcd you should have that ax + by = gcd.  Check this, and if it is not happening then you know that's where your problem is.

Comment: @TheGreatContini: His egcd is correct, but it will return a negative number sometimes (correct behavior). He merely has to add phi(n) to the answer when that happens.